# How does Parallel.ForEach handles cancellation or ThrowIfCancellationRequested() and exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task-parallel-library

I created a WPF app to see how TPL works and I'm confused by the output I had. Below is my code:

```
// Two buttons, 'Process' button and 'Cancel' button
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
   private CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
   //...

   private void cmdProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Sequence A
   {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessFiles()); 
   }

    private void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //Sequence B
   {
      cancelToken.Cancel();  
   }

   private void ProcessFiles() 
   {
      ParallelOptions parOpts = new ParallelOptions();
      parOpts.CancellationToken = cancelToken.Token;
      parOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

      string[] files = { "first", "second" };
      try
      {
         Parallel.ForEach(files, parOpts, currentFile =>
         {
            parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();  //Sequence C
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
         });
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
      { 
         MessageBox.Show("Caught");
      }
   }

}
```

When I press the `click` button and then press the `cancel` button quickly, I get a "Caught" message box popping up only once, not twice.

Let's say the primary thread id is 1, and worker threads are 2 and 3
so I have two questions:

Q1- when I press the `cancel` button, worker threads 2 and 3 have already executed 'parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();' (of course my mouse click cannot be as fast as a thread's execution). When they execute ThrowIfCancellationRequested, the cancelToken hasn't been cancelled, which means that the cancel button has not been clicked for thread 2 and thread 3. So how come those worker threads still throw an exception?

Q2- why do I only get one popup message box, shouldn't it be two, one for thread 2 and one for thread 3?

Q3- I modified the Parallel.ForEach as:

```
try
{
   Parallel.ForEach(files, parOpts, currentFile =>
   {
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 

   });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{ 
   MessageBox.Show("Caught");
}
```

now I can press cancel button before worker thread reaches to ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), but I still get only one exception thrown by the primary thread. BUt I pressed the cancal button, token has been set to cancel, so when the secondary worker thread reaches to  `parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`, shouldn't it throw an exception too? and this exception cannot be handled by the try catch in the primary thread(each thread has its own stack), so I should get an unhandled exception to halt the application, but it wasn't, I just get one exception thrown by primary thread, and is this exception thrown by primary thread or worker thread?

Q4-I modify the code as:

```
private void ProcessFilesz()
{
    ParallelOptions parOpts = new ParallelOptions();
    parOpts.CancellationToken = cancelToken.Token;
    parOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

    cancelToken.Cancel(); // cancel here
    string[] files = { "first", "second" };
    try
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(files, parOpts, currentFile =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Underline Thread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
            parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        });

    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("catch");
    }
}
```

again there is sth weird, there is no messagebox popup, even though the token is set to cancel, but `MessageBox.Show(...)` statement is above the statement of `parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`, so the `MessageBox.Show()` should be executed first, but why it is not executed at all? or CLR hoists `parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` to the top to be first statement implicitly?

Q5- I modified the code as:

```
try
{
   Parallel.ForEach(files, parOpts, currentFile =>
   {
      Thread.Sleep(5000); // I pressed the cancel button on the main thread when the worker thread is sleeping
   });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Caught");
}
```

so I have enough time to press the cancel button, there is one "catch" message, but why there is still an exception? Now I understand that Parallel.ForEach checks CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` before all resource expensive operations, does it mean that Parallel.ForEach will check IsCancellationRequested after all statements inside have been executed? I mean Parallel.ForEach will check IsCancellationRequested twice, one before first statement, and one after the last statement?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195656/discussion-on-question-by-secondimage-throwifcancellationrequested-and-cancell).

Comment: Ok, to make it clear: the array contains two strings that should simulate the work load, right? The **primary** thread is the thread you created to execute the `Parallel.ForEach` loop using `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessFiles());`. The `Parallel.ForEach` then execute (on the primary thread) and might create two worker threads (one for each load or string).

Comment: There are two scenarios. _First scenario_: you invoke the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in your action delegate: When you surround your action code with a try-catch, then no exceptions leaves the worker thread. If there is no such try-catch, the `Parallel.ForEach` catches the exception. This would be  on the primary thread. This exception is re-thrown. But since you invoked `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on the worker the origin is the worker thread.

Comment: _Second scenario_: you don't explicitly call `CancellationToke.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in your action or the cancellation ocurres _after_ the `CancellationToke.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method, then the next time `Parallel.ForEach` checks `CancellationToke.IsCancelRequested`, it will throw the exception. Since `Parallel.ForEach executes on the primary thread, the origin of the exception will be the primary thread.

Comment: Please check my answer again. I updated it to address your question about the actual thread count and definition of primary and  worker thread. Scroll down to get the summary of how and on which threads exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @BionicCode   I think I got it. Thank you. But still a new question. I added a Q4 in my post, could you have a look, I promise it is the last question :)

Comment: I checked your code. The expected behaviour is that the loop will not execute at all. `Parallel.ForEach` will directly cancel execution and throw an `OperationCanceledException`, because one of the first steps of `Parallel.ForEach` is to check `CancellationToken.IsCancelRequested` to avoid unnecessary work. So there must be the 'catch' message from the outer `catch` block showing up. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @BionicCode yes, there was just one "catch" message. So you mean the purpose of `parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is to check if the token set to cancel after a thread has been execute at least the first statement?

Comment: No. The purpose of `parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is to throw an exception immediately, when `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` evaluates to true. I already posted the implementation of `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in my answer before. From there you can see that there is no magic going on, just simple exception throwing. The reason is that the `Cancellation.Token` was set to 'cancel' _BEFORE_ the `Parallel.ForEach` executes.

Comment: I told you several times that `Parallel.ForEach checks  `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` _before_ all resource expensive operations. So you must agree that it doesn't make sense to create threads when the loop was already cancelled, right? So you code never makes it past `Parallel.ForEach(files, parOpts, currentFile => ...)` this instruction.

Comment: The instruction pointer enters the `Parallel.ForEach()` method and throws immediately an `OperationCanceledException`. No further creation of threads or any other execution than the throwing of this exception. Instruction pointer leaves the method since the OS interrupts the application and starts to search for a registered `catch` handler, do you remember? You provided a `catch` handler, so it is executed, hence showing the 'catched' message.

Comment: This checking if `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` is done by all _TPL_ classes that perform resource expensive operations: first validation of the parameters (NULL-checks etc), then testing the `CancellationToken`. If the token is set to cancel state, then they all throw the `OperationCanceledException`, what aborts any further execution and starts the exception handling procedure. You can try it with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @BionicCode  OK. Thank you so much for your time. one last question,  could you take a look at Q5? It seems that  Parallel.ForEach will check IsCancellationRequested twice, one before first statement, and one after the last statement?

Comment: No problem. I like that you are interested in the details and that you try out things to research the behaviour.

Comment: Regarding Q5: yes, you're correct. In my answer I already wrote "... the framework checks the cancellation token multiple times during execution for the purpose of efficiency. The `Parallel.ForEach` e.g. has to do many of this expensive resource allocations due to all the thread management. Before _each_ allocation step (e.g. initialization, spawning worker threads or forking, applying partitioner, invoking the action, etc) the `CancellationToken.IsCancelRequested` is evaluated again. The last internal `Parallel.ForEach` step is joining the threads before creating the `ParallelLoopResult`...".

Comment: So, there are multiple tests of the `CancellationToken` cancel state during the execution of _all_ _TPL_ classes (with cancellation suppport), not only two checks. Maybe you should read my answer once more.

Comment: @BionicCode  thanks a million. Now I'm really confidently dealing with TPL :)

Comment: Great. Don't worry. Your attitude to learning is really nice. This will get you far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How `Parallel.ForEach` handles cancellation##

Your observations are correct. But everything behaves normal. Since the `ParallelOptions.CancellationToken` property is set, the `Parallel.ForEach` throws the `OperationCanceledException` once `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` evaluates to true.

All framework classes that support cancellation behave like this (e.g. `Task.Run`). Before any expensive resource allocations are executed (expensive in memory or time), the framework checks the cancellation token multiple times during execution for the purpose of efficiency. The `Parallel.ForEach` e.g. has to do many of this expensive resource allocations due to all the thread management. Before *each* allocation step (e.g. initialization, spawning worker threads or forking, applying partitioner, invoking the action, etc) the `CancellationToken.IsCancelRequested` is evaluated again.

The last internal `Parallel.ForEach` step is joining the threads before creating the `ParallelLoopResult` (the return value of `Parallel.ForEach`). Before this operation the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` is again evaluated. Since you canceled the execution of the `Parallel.ForEach` while the `Thread.Sleep(5000)` is executing, you have to wait for a maximum span of 5 seconds until the framework rechecks this property and can throw the `OperationCanceledException`. You can test this. It will take x/1000 seconds of `Thread.Sleep(x)` to elapse until the `MessageBox` will show.

Another chance to cancel the `Parallel.ForEach` is delegated to the consumer. It is very likely that the consumer's action is long running and therefore requires cancellation *before* the end of the `Parallel.ForEach` is reached. As you know, the premature cancellation can be forced by (repeatedly) invoking `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, which this time will make the `CancellationToken` throw the `OperationCanceledException` (and not the `Parallel.ForEach`).

To answer your last question why you only will see *one* `MessageBox`: in your special case you already noticed, that you are too slow to click the cancel button before the code reaches `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, but able to click it before the thread wakes up from sleep. Therefore the `Parallel.ForEach` throws the exception (before joining threads and the creation of the `ParallelLoopResult`). So *one* exception is thrown. But even if you are fast enough to cancel the loop before reaching `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, there still would be only one `MessageBox` showing since the loop aborts all threads, as soon an uncatched exception was thrown. To allow each thread to throw an exception you must catch each and accumulate them, before throwing them wrapped in an `AggregateException`. See: [Microsoft Docs: How to Handle Exceptions in Parallel Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops) for more details.

---

**Edit to answer follow-up question:**

> For Q2, I just realized each thread has its own stack, so it won't
> know that it is surrounded by a try catch block, that's why there is
> only one exception(thrown by primary thread), is my understanding
> correct?

You are right when saying each thread has it's dedicated call stack. But when you write code that is supposed to be executed concurrently, than a copy of all locals is created on the heap for each thread. This is also true for `try-catch` blocks. `Catch` instructs the compiler to define a handler (instruction pointer) that is then registered to an exception handler table by the `try` instruction. The table is managed by the OS. The exception table maps a each handler to an exception. Each exception is mapped to a call stack. So exceptions and catch handlers are restricted to an explicit call stack. Since the handler has access to thread local memory, it must be a copy as well. This means each thread is 'aware' of its `catch` handlers.

Due to the dedicated call stacks and the exclusive mapping of exception to call stack and catch handler to exception (and thus also to the call stack), any exception thrown in a thread's scope (call stack) can't be caught outside the scope of the thread (when using `Thread`). Scope means in this case the address space that it described by the call stack (with its call frames). Unless not caught directly in the thread itself, it will crash the application. `Task` (when awaited either using `Task.Wait` or `await`) on the contrary, swallows all exceptions and wraps them in an `AggregateException`.

An exception thrown by `DoParallel()` will not be caught:

```
try 
{
  Thread thread = new Thread(() => DoParallel());
  thread.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Unreachable code
}
```

But in the following two examples, both `catch` handlers are invoked to handle the exception:

```
try 
{
  await Task.Run(() => DoParallel());
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
  // Reachable code
}
```

or

```
try 
{
  var task = new Task(() => DoParallel());
  task.Start();
  task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
  // Reachable code
}
```

The last two examples are using the *Task Parallel Library - TPL* which uses a `SynchronizationContext` to allow threads to share context and therefore e.g. to propagate exceptions between the threads. Since `Parallel.ForEach` uses `Task.Wait()` (*TPL*), it is able to catch the worker thread's exception (if you didn't already caught it inside your action), to perform some cleanup (cancel other worker threads and disposal of internal resources), and then finally to propagate the `OperationCanceledException` to the outer scope.

So because an exception is thrown,

- the OS interrupts the application and checks the exception table for a potential handler that was mapped to this thread by the `try` directive.
- It finds one and reconstructs the context to execute the `catch`
  handler (in your case, the next `catch` handler is the internal handler of `Parallel.ForEach`). Application is still on halt - other
  threads are still parked.
- This `Parallel.ForEach` handler performs the clean up and ends other
  threads *before* the application continues and therefore *before* any of the worker threads
  can throw additional exceptions themselves.
- The application continues by executing the re-`throw` of the `Parallel.ForEach` `catch`
  handler.
- Application halts again looking for an outer scope (consumer scope of `Parallel.ForEach`)
  `catch` handler.
- If none was registered using `try`, the application will terminate with an error.

That's why there is always *one* exception thrown by `Parallel.ForEach`.

---

**Edit to answer follow-up question Q3:**

> now I can press cancel button before worker thread reaches to ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), but I still get only one exception thrown by the primary thread. BUt I pressed the cancal button, token has been set to cancel, so when the secondary worker thread reaches to parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();, shouldn't it throw an exception too? and this exception cannot be handled by the try catch in the primary thread(each thread has its own stack), so I should get an unhandled exception to halt the application, but it wasn't, I just get one exception thrown by primary thread, and is this exception thrown by primary thread or worker thread

for the following scenario:

```
try
{
   Parallel.ForEach(files, parOpts, currentFile =>
   {
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      parOpts.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 

   });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{ 
   MessageBox.Show("Caught");
}
```

Since in this scenario you are able to cancel the `Parallel.ForEach` before it completes, the exception is generated on the worker thread (that executes your action delegate), the moment `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is executed. Under the hood the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method simply looks like:

```
public void ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
{
  if (IsCancellationRequested) 
    ThrowOperationCanceledException();
}

// Throws an OCE; separated out to enable better inlining of ThrowIfCancellationRequested
private void ThrowOperationCanceledException()
{
  throw new OperationCanceledException(Environment.GetResourceString("OperationCanceled"), this);
}
```

As I mentioned before, the `Parallel.ForEach` uses `Task` and `Task.Wait() (_TPL_)` to handle threads and therefore uses a `SynchronizationContext`. In the scenario of *TPL* (or `SynchronizationContext`), the thread contexts are shared and no longer isolated (in contrast to `Thread` threads). This allows the `Parallel.ForEach` to catch exceptions thrown by child threads.

This means, there are no unhandled exceptions inside the `Parallel.ForEach`, since, as you can read in the step-by-step explanation of the exception flow, `Parallel.ForEach` internally catches all exceptions (possible due to *TPL*) to do the clean up and disposal of allocated resources and then finally to re-throw the `OperationCanceledException`.

When checking the exception's call stack of your Q3 code example, you will see that the origin is the worker thread and not the 'primary' `Parallel.ForEach` thread. You just caught the exception in the primary thread, since it contains the `catch` handler closest to the origin - the worker thread. Because of this, the primary thread can complete without cancellation.

---

### Parallel.ForEach and threads

I think your understanding is wrong:

> ...the primary thread is also executing the statements in Parallel.ForEach, isn't it? I have a typo in the post, there is only two active threads, not three. the string[] just have two elements, so primary thread takes "first" to process and one worker thread takes "two" to process...

This is not true. To make it clear: the array in your initial example contains two strings that are supposed to simulate the work load, right? The primary thread is the thread you've created to execute the `Parallel.ForEach` loop using `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessFiles());`. This is a common practice in order to keep the UI thread responsive during a long running `Parallel.ForEach`. The `Parallel.ForEach` therefore executes on the primary thread and *might* create two worker threads - one for each load (or string). *Might* because the `Parallel.ForEach` actually uses *tasks*, that are backed up by *threads*. The max *thread* count is limited by the processor count and the `TaskScheduler`. Due to performance optimizations executed by the framework, the actual number of *tasks* must not match the number of iterated items or the value of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

> The `Parallel.ForEach` method may use more tasks than threads over the lifetime of its execution, as existing tasks complete and are replaced by new tasks. This gives the underlying `TaskScheduler` object the chance to add, change, or remove threads that service the loop.
> may decide to execute the action delegates on fewer threads then the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` allows. (source: [Microsoft Docs: Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_ForEach__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_System_Func___1__System_Func___0_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState___1___1__System_Action___1__))

---

### To generalize it and to sum it up

Assuming that the `ParallelOptions.CancellationToken` property is set, there are two possible scenarios:

*First scenario:* you did invoke the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in your action delegate *after* cancellation was requested, but *before* `Parallel.ForEach` internally evaluates `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`. Now in case you surround your action code with a `try-catch`, then no exception leaves the worker thread. If there is no such `try-catch`, the `Parallel.ForEach` will internally catch this exception (to do some clean up). This would be on the primary thread. This exception is then re-thrown after the `Parallel.ForEach` has disposed allocated resources. Because you invoked `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on the worker, the origin is still this worker thread. Besides a cancellation request, any exception can stop the execution of `Parallel.ForEach` at any time.

*Second scenario:* you *don't* explicitly call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in your action delegate or the cancellation occurred *after* the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method was invoked, then the next time `Parallel.ForEach` internally checks `CancellationToken.IsCancelRequested`, the exception will be thrown by the `Parallel.ForEach`. `Parallel.ForEach` always evaluates `CancellationToken.IsCancelRequested` before allocating any resources. Since `Parallel.ForEach` executes on the primary thread, the origin of this exception will be of course the primary thread. Besides a cancellation request, any exception can stop the execution of `Parallel.ForEach` at any time.

When the `ParallelOptions.CancellationToken` property is not set, then the internal `Parallel.ForEach` evaluations of `CancellationToken.IsCancelRequested` will not occur. In case of a `CancellationToken.Cancel()` request, the `Parallel.ForEach`can not react and will continue its resource intensive work, *unless* there is no exception thrown by an invocation of `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. Besides a cancellation request, any exception can stop the execution of `Parallel.ForEach` at any time.

Comment: I didn't know CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested will be again evaluated, that makes sense now. For Q2, I just realized each thread has its own stack, so it won't know that it is surrounded by a try catch block, that's why there is only one exception(thrown by primary thread), is my understanding correct?

Comment: @secondimage I extended the answer for your follow-up question.

Comment: I think in C there is no such a thing that a copy of all locals is created on the heap? Anyway, I raised another question in regards to thread stack, could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793050/why-a-worker-threads-exception-cannot-be-caught-in-this-way

Comment: @secondimage  C doesn't support multithreading natively (standard library). You need extended library like POSIX.(pthread). It works basically the same. Locals (unshared memory) must be copied otherwise threads would overwrite each others memory values (which is the case for shared memory).

Comment: @secondimage I updated the answer (part with the exception example) to make it more clear why exceptions can't travel outside the thread's scope (thread scope = call stack).

Comment: hi bro, could you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818733/why-the-primary-thread-disappear/56819302#56819302