# Async/ Await: why does the code that follows await is also executed on the background thread and not on the original primary thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, async-await, clr

Below is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        string message = await DoWorkAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    static async Task<string> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3_000);
            return "Done with work!";
        });
    }
}
```

and the output is

> 1

// after 3 secs

> 3
>
> Done with work!

so you can see the main thread(id is 1) changed to worker thread(id is 3), so how come the main thread just disappear?

Comment: Read [Paulo Morgado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402366/paulo-morgado)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819302/267), and then explain why this matters? Is it just "I saw this and I wonder why" or is it "I have a problem in my code and think this might be the reason"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of application type you chose. Console apps and GUI apps behave differently regarding the `SynchronizationContext`. When you use `await`, then the current `SynchronizationContext` is captured and passed to the background thread.
The idea is not to block the main thread by just waiting for the background thread to complete. The remaining code is enqueued and the current context stored in the `SynchronizationContext` which the backgroung thread wil capture. When the background thread completes, it returns the captured `SynchronizationContext` so that the enqueued remaining code can resume execution. You can get the current context by accessing `SynchronizationContext.Current` property. The code that is waiting for `await` to finish (the remaining code after `await`) will be enqueued as a continuation and executed on the captured `SynchronizationContext`.

The default value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` is the UI thread for GUI applications like WPF or NULL for console applications. Console applications don't have a `SynchronizationContext`, so to be able to use `async`, the framwork uses the `ThreadPool` `SynchronizationContext`. The rules for the `SynchronizationContext` behaviour is that

1. If the `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns NULL, the
   continuation thread will default to a thread pool thread
2. If `SynchronizationContext.Current` is not NULL, the continuation
   will be executed on the captured context.
3. And: if the `await` is used on a background thread (hence a new
   background thread is started from a background thread), then the
   `SynchronizationContext` will always be a thread pool thread.

**Scenario 1, a console application:**
rule 1) applies: *thread 1* calls `await` which will try to capture the current context. `await` will use the background thread *thread 3* from the `ThreadPool` to execute the asynchronous delegate.
Once the delegate completes, the remaining code of the calling thread will execute on the captured context. Since this context is NULL in console applications, the default `SynchronizationContext` will take effect (first rule). Therefore the scheduler decides to continue execution on the `ThreadPool` thread *thread 3* (for efficiency. Context switches are expensive).

**Scenario 2, a GUI application:**
rule 2) applies: *thread 1* calls `await` which will try to capture the current context (the UI `SynchronizationContext`). `await` will use the background thread *thread 3* from the `ThreadPool` to execute the asynchronous delegate.
Once the delegate completes, the remaining code of the calling thread will execute on the captured context, the UI `SynchronizationContext` *thread 1*.

**Scenario 3, a GUI application and `Task.ContinueWith`:**
rule 2) and rule 3) applies: *thread 1* calls `await` which will try to capture the current context (the UI `SynchronizationContext`). `await` will use the background thread *thread 3* from the `ThreadPool` to execute the asynchronous delegate.   Once the delegate completes, the continuation `TaskContinueWith`. Since we are still on the background thread, a new `TreadPool` thread *thread 4* is used with the captured `SynchronizationContext` of *thread 3*. Once the continuation completes the context returns to *thread 3* which will execute the remaining code of the caller on the captured `SynchronizationContext` which is the UI thread *thread 1*.

**Scenario 4, a GUI application and `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` (`await DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`):**
rule 1) applies: *thread 1* calls `await` and executes the asynchronous delegate on a `ThreadPool` background thread *thread 3*. But because the task was configured with `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` *thread 3* doesn't capture the `SynchronizationContext` of the caller (UI `SynchronizationContext`). The `SynchronizationContext.Current` property of thread 3 will therefore be NULL and the default `SynchronizationContext` applies: the context will be a `ThreadPool` thread. Because of performance optimizations (context switching is expensive) the context will be the current `SynchronizationContext` of *thread 3*. This means that once *thread 3* completes, the remaining code of hte caller will be executed on the default `SynchronizationContext`  *thread 3*. The default `Task.ConfigureAwait` value is `true`,  which enables capturing of the caller `SynchronizationContext`.

**Scenario 5, a GUI application and `Task.Wait`, `Task.Result` or `Task.GetAwaiter.GetResult`:**
rule 2 applies but the application will deadlock. The current `SynchronizationContext` of *thread 1* is captured. But because the asynchronous delegate is executed synchronously (`Task.Wait`, `Task.Result` or `Task.GetAwaiter.GetResult` will turn the asynchronous operation into a synchronous execution of the delegate), *thread 1* will block until the now synchronous delegate completes.
Since the code is executed synchronously the remaining code of *thread 1* was not enqueued as continuation of *thread 3* and will therefore execute on *thread 1* once the delegate completes. Now that the delegate on *thread 3* completes it cannot return the `SynchronizationContext` of *thread 1* to *thread 1*, because *thread 1* is still blocking (and thus locking the `SynchronizationContext`). *Thread 3* will wait infinitely for *thread 1* to release the lock on `SynchronizationContext`, which in turn makes *thread 1* wait infinitely for *thread 3* to return --> deadlock.

**Scenario 6, console application and `Task.Wait`, `Task.Result` or `Task.GetAwaiter.GetResult`:**
rule 1 applies. The current `SynchronizationContext` of *thread 1* is captured. But because this is a console application the context is NULL and the default `SynchronizationContext` applies. The asynchronous delegate is executed synchronously (`Task.Wait`, `Task.Result` or `Task.GetAwaiter.GetResult` will turn the asynchronous operation into a synchronous operation) on a `ThreadPool` background thread *thread 3* and *thread 1* will block until the delegate on *thread 3* completes. Since the code is executed synchronously the remaining code was not enqueued as continuation of *thread 3* and will therefore execute on *thread 1* once the delegate completes. No deadlock situation in case of a console aplication, since the `SynchronizationContext` of *thread 1* was NULL and *thread 3* has to use the default context.

The code of your example matches scenario 1. It#s because you are running a console application and the default `SynchronizationContext` that applies because the `SynchronizationContext` of console applications is always NULL. When the captured `SynchronizationContext` is NULL, `Task` uses the default context which is a thread of the `ThreadPool`. Since the asynchronous delegate is already executed on a `ThreadPool`  thread the `TaskScheduler` decides to stay on this thread and therefore to execute the enqueued remaining  code  of the caller thread  *thread 1* in *thread 3*.

In GUI applications it's best practice to always use `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere except you explicitly want to capture the `SynchronizationContext` of the caller. This will prevent accidental deadlocks in you application.

Comment: There's no `SynchronizationContext` on console applications.

Comment: Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` is recommended when the following code is not required to run in the  `SynchronizationContext` because it's a precious resource that should not be wasted. Besides that, avoids thread switching.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Thank you. I think I wrote several times that console applications don't have a `SynchronizationContext` and that console application's `SynchgronizationContext.Current` returns always NULL  and that because of this, the default `ThreadPool` `SynchronizationContext` applies.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I think most of the time it is not required to resume the remaining code on the captured context.

Comment: @BionicCode  thank you for your answer again, could you also take a look at this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831919/whats-the-benefits-of-using-taskcompletionsource-over-task-run?noredirect=1#comment100215824_56831919

Comment: @BionicCode  Hi I reviewed my knowledge in async programming and have new questions, could you have a look please? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841920/does-asynccallback-get-executed-when-there-is-exception-thrown-at-the-worker-thr

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronous entry point is just a compiler trick. Behind the scenes, the compiler generates this real entry point:

```
private static void <Main>(string[] args)
{
    _Main(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

If you change your code to be like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }


    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        string message = await DoWorkAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    static async Task<string> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3_000);
        return "Done with work!";
    }
}
```

You'll get this:

```
1
4
Done with work!
1
```

As expected, the main thread is waiting for the work to be done.

Comment: `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` synchronizes the async delegate, which will block the main thread. It's (almost) equivalent to `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result`. Because the operation is synchronized, the compiler won't enqueue the remaining code as a continuation and just executes it on its own thread, after the execution of the delegate has completed.

Comment: Async works like this: to prevent the main thread from blocking (waiting), the remaining code is enqueued and the current `SynchronizationContext` released - the main thread is 'free'. No waiting and therefore no blocking. After the delegates completes, it returns the captured `SynchronizationContext` to continue the execution of the enqueued remaining code on it.

Comment: There's no `SynchronizationContext` on console applications.

Comment: I know. But I was not referring to console applications. I was describing the async flow in general, as it also applies for console applications. Since the `SynchronizationContext.Current` of console applications will always returns NULL, the framework will use a fallback context, which is a `ThreadPool` context.

Comment: @PauloMorgado   Hi bro, could you also have a look at this question, please? Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841920/does-asynccallback-get-invoked-when-there-is-exception-thrown-at-the-worker-thre?noredirect=1#comment102120654_57841920

Answer (score 0):

In your code your main thread ends once it calls `await` here:

```
string message = await DoWorkAsync();
```

Where the execution will diverge since `DoWorkAsync()` creates a task and all the code after that call will be executed within the new created task, then the main thread has nothing to do after calling `await DoWorkAsync();` so it will be done.

Comment: how could a primary thread ends before a secondary thread? Isn't that a primary thread always wait for the secondary thread to be finished?

Comment: No it gets done once it has nothing to do if you make no measures to wait for created threads like calling `Wait()` method instead of `await` in your case.

Comment: In general you need to understand the difference between thread and process, foreground and background threads. Your application which is a single process one gets done once all `Foreground` threads get done i.e. The main thread and the one created for the new task. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads)

Comment: But there are still two statements below `string message = await DoWorkAsync();`, shouldn't the main thread execute those two statements? And those two statements are executed by the worker thread?

Comment: No as I said previously all of your code after `await` will be executed within the new created thread of the task you created, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/control-flow-in-async-programs) to understand the flow.