# does AsyncCallback get invoked when there is exception thrown at the worker thread

Tags: .net, asynchronous, threadpool, clr

I'm new to .net asynchronous programming(Asynchronous Programming Model), just have two questions on the relationship of worker thread and exceptions. Below is an example:

```
private void OnPerformSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/#q=weather");
    req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Callback), req);  // here the main thread calls BeginGetResponse() to enqueues the work in threadpool then a worker thread A will get the job done
    ...// do other stuff 
}

private void Callback(IAsyncResult iar)
{
   WebRequest req = (WebRequest) iar.AsyncState;
   try
   {
      WebResponse resp = req.EndGetResponse(iar);
      ProcessResponse(resp);
   }
   catch(Exception x)
   {
      LogError(x);
   }
}
```

Q1-We know that `BeginGetResponse` method enqueues the work in threadpool  and returns immediately, and the caller can now get on with other work, and then a worker thread (let's it is thread A) in the thread pool will get the job done. My question is, when the thread A finished the work, is the threadpool going to assign a different worker thread(thread B) to invoke the  completion callback? or the thread A will continue to invoke the callback?

Q2-we know that the completion callback that gets invoked when the async operation completes. But if there is error when the worker thread A was doing the job, will the work be deemed as "completed" so that the callback can be invoked? or the process just get stuck forever until we restart the application?

Comment: You are not allowed to make any assumptions about which particular thread handles the callback.  It is possible that it might be the same thread when it was also a threadpool thread that called BeginGetResponse().  But that would be accidental.  Any errors that occurred while trying to start the request are raised on thread A and won't cause a callback.  But they are "bad code" kind of exceptions that shouldn't be caught.

Comment: @HansPassant  it is the main thread called `BeginGetResponse()`, not any worker threads in threadpool. the main thread call the method to enqueues the work then threadpool assigns a worker thread to get the work done. so do you mean main thread can also possibly handles the callback?

Comment: The main thread is not a threadpool thread.  So no.  Hard to see the point of these questions when primary directive is "you are not allowed to make any assumptions".

Comment: @HansPassant so if an error occurs at thread A,  according to what you said, the callback wont be invoked, but I need to call the `EndGetResponse()` in the callback to free up resource, since the callback won't be invoked, the resource can never be free?

Comment: What from @HansPassant answer could lead you to the assumption that callback won't be called? If thread A is a main thread and it called `BeginGetResponse()` and then fail with the exception, callback will still get invoked.

Comment: @Fenixil  thread A is the worker thread not the main thread. What I mean is that there is no error in the main thread but there is an error occurs in  thread A, so in this case, will the callback still be invoked?

Comment: If thread A is just another thread pool thread that did some unrelated staff which throwed an exception... just go and check what will happen with your application ;)      `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => throw new Exception(""));`

Comment: @Fenixil  There will be an unhandled  exception thrown and to my surprise the process didn't get terminated, the main thread still execute, don't know why. but  the approach is not APM approach anyway. Whay I mean is, when the worker thread A was doing the job that cause an error, then the job will never be deemed as "completed" or is throw an exception is a way of completed status?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what is the place of thread A in your example, what job it is doing and who check job's status to deem it completed. Please provide an example in your question with implementation.

Comment: @Fenixil sure, let me explain it further. The main thread  enqueues the job in threadpool, then the main thread does sth else. a little bit later on, threadpool let a worker thread A to do the job. So thread A is executing the job, but the job as some bad code like `int num =0/0`, which throws an DivideByZeroException. Normally the callback method get invoked when the worker thread finishes a job, but in my case, the job is not considered(and will bot be consider) as completed due to the exception, so the callback method will never get called, is my understanding correct?

Comment: @secondimage, have you tested your assumptions you're making on threading? What tests have you done to assert the exception will/won't be notified on the completion callback?

Comment: @PauloMorgado yes, I did write a small program to  test my assumptions, the callback will still be called regardless of the existence of exceptions. And the exception will be re-throw when I call `EndGetResponse()` , so I need to have exception handler around the End method. I get the idea, but what if the main thread finished and tear down all worker threads, the worker thread still doesn't have a chance to call `EndGetResponse()` to free resource?

Comment: @PauloMorgado  another question is that, I tried my program many times, the worker thread id is the same as the callback thread id, so does it mean that once the worker thread finishes the job, it will always continue to execute the callback method?

Comment: You're assuming there are threads attached to all this, which is wrong. which type of application is your test application? Console? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: @PauloMorgado its console application, threads attached to all this what do you mean by "threads attached to all this"?

Comment: The `BeginXXX` does not send anything to the thread pool. It registers the a callback that will post to the thread pool the invocation of `Callback`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado  below is quoted from my textbook, is anything wrong in the statement?: "**The idea is that the BeginGetResults method enqueues the work and returns immediately, and the caller can now get on with other work. In most cases the work will occur asynchronously on the thread pool. The EndGetResults method is used to retrieve the results of the completed asynchronous operation.**"

Comment: Callback will always be invoked asynchronously (from the main thread). Not 'in most cases'. I'm glad you described everything with words, but that's not what I expected when asked for implementation - write code please.